# Error converting Json file to a feature class

Tags: arcpy, convert, json, python-3

I want to convert some json data being returned from a request to a feature class, but I keep getting a `RuntimeError: Object: Error in executing tool`. I made a test gdb in a folder 'C:/Workspace/Sandbox/ScratchTests/cslf.gdb' in which to populate my new feature class after conversion. To test that the request is correct and that I am returning Json data, I added a couple of print statements. Otherwise, everything is pretty straight forward. Does anyone see a problem with my code? I am following the arcpy [JSON to Features][1] directions from the documentation. The only thing I am doing differently is instead of using an actual file, I am just plugging in the variable 'cslfJson`.

```
import arcpy, sys, os, arcgis, requests
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/Workspace/Sandbox/ScratchTests"

params = {'f': 'json', 'where': '1=1', 'geometryType': 'esriGeometryPolygon', 'spatialRel': 'esriSpatialRelIntersects','outFields': '*', 'returnGeometry': 'false'}
r = requests.get('https://hazards.fema.gov/gis/nfhl/rest/services/CSLF/Prelim_CSLF/MapServer/3/query', params)
print(r.url)

cslfJson = r.json()
print(cslfJson)

arcpy.JSONToFeatures_conversion(cslfJson, os.path.join("cslf.gdb", "cslf"))
```

Also, Here's the Traceback:

> https://hazards.fema.gov/gis/nfhl/rest/services/CSLF/Prelim_CSLF/MapServer/3/query?f=json&where=1%3D1&geometryType=esriGeometryPolygon&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&outFields=%2A&returnGeometry=false
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       runfile('C:/Workspace/Sandbox/ScratchTests/CSLF.py', wdir='C:/Workspace/Sandbox/ScratchTests')
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\jbridwell\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\acrpro\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py",
>   line 668, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\jbridwell\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\acrpro\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py",
>   line 108, in execfile
>       exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
>
> File "C:/Workspace/Sandbox/ScratchTests/CSLF.py", line 20, in
>   
>       arcpy.JSONToFeatures_conversion(cslfJson, os.path.join("cslf.gdb", "cslf"))
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\conversion.py", line 403, in
>   JSONToFeatures
>       raise e
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\conversion.py", line 400, in
>   JSONToFeatures
>       retval = convertArcObjectToPythonObject(gp.JSONToFeatures_conversion(*gp_fixargs((in_json_file,
>   out_features), True)))
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\geoprocessing_base.py", line
>   506, in 
>       return lambda *args: val(*gp_fixargs(args, True))
>
> RuntimeError: Object: Error in executing tool
>
> [1]:
>   http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/conversion-toolbox/json-to-features.htm

Comment: whats the error you're getting? there was a known BUG in their PRO release be sure to have the latest patch to circumvent this known issue.

Comment: Hmmm, I'll add the traceback, but actual error I'm seeing (I'm using Spyder with Python 3.6 from AcrGIS Pro), was `RuntimeError: Object: Error in executing tool`. See the Traceback for details.

Comment: yah be sure to install the 2.2 patch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually able to get this to work without updating to 2.2. Essentially, I had to turn the json data into a physical file in order for it to work. This is a little cumbersome, but as the file should get overwritten each time I run the script (as the REST service data is updated) it should be fine. I just added a part at then end to open a file and then write to that file, then use the newly created json file in JSONToFeatures_conversion:

```
cslfJson = r.json()
path = r"C:/Workspace/Sandbox/ScratchTests/cslf.json"
with open(path, 'w') as f:
     json.dump(cslfJson, f, indent=2)

arcpy.JSONToFeatures_conversion("cslf.json", os.path.join("cslf.gdb", "cslf"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to have the latest [ArcGIS PRO patch release (2.2.1)](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/get-started/release-notes.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_55F27555C9504FEAB6BC08FA7EEF4A83)

There were known issues in previous releases dealing with JSON conversions.

- BUG-000115464

GeoJSON to Features crashes ArcGIS Pro at GPCoreFunctions!Bucket_JSON2F::UnionProperties (gpesrijsontofeaturesfunction.cpp @ 1029).

- BUG-000110564

The Key Metadata function fails to run a JSON Metadata String in ArcGIS Pro, even with a valid input.

these BUGS are not limited to your issue but will affect your processing. Implement the patch and see if it clears the problem.

Comment: I'm running 2.1.2. Will the latest patch work with my version (2.2)?

Comment: no you need to update PRO to 2.2.1